# What access Level do i need to get to access a users full profile and positions in the v2 api?

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

I want to know what access level from the below products that I have to get access to to get an authenticated users full profile information and positions through the V2 api.

I had this working from the V1 api with a basic profile permission , i see in this documentation that there is a r_fullprofile,https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile
 but it is not clear what access level needs to be obtained to receive this permission on and app.

it looks like these are the different "enterprise products" to apply for

1. Marketing Developer Platform
2. Sales Navigator Display
3. Sales Navigator Analytics
4. Recruiter System Connect
5. Apply with LinkedIn
6. Easy Apply

but it doesn't say which one give you what access.

There is also this page where to actually ask for the access 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/
there are options here tat don't coincide with the ones in the other documentation

1. Compliance
2. Consumer
3. Learner
4. Marketing
5. Sales
6. Talent

I am assuming that i will need to query the api like 
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,address,positions)&oauth2_access_token=someaccesstoken

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible to get r_fullprofile, and it's looks like it won't be.**

Message from Linh (LinkedIn Developer Support)
(Aug 11, 2020, 5:02 AM PDT)

> Hi Andrey,
>
> I'm happy to help!
>
> r_fullprofile is not being granted at this time and there are no
> immediate plans to change the provisioning of the permission. I
> apologize for the inconvenience. Please see documentation here for
> details on profile fields available with v2 apps:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api-v1-migration
>
> Please let me know if there is anything else I can assist you with!
> --
>
> Linh  Developer Support
>
> Stay up to date with developer news:
> https://www.linkedin.com/content/developers/news